# Problem with .only() method, passing to Pagination / Serialization --- all fields are getting returned instead of the ones specified in only()

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, paginator

I am trying load some data into datatables. I am trying to specify columns in the model.objects query by using .only() --- at first glance at the resulting QuerySet, it does in fact look like the mySQL query is only asking for those columns.

However, When I try to pass the QuerySet into Paginator, and/or a Serializer, the result has ALL columns in it.

I cannot use .values_list() because that does not return the nested objects that I need to have serialized as part of my specific column ask. I am not sure what is happening to my .only()

```
db_result_object = model.objects.prefetch_related().filter(qs).order_by(asc+sort_by).only(*columns_to_return)

    paginated_results = Paginator(db_result_object,results_per_page)
    serialized_results = serializer(paginated_results.object_list,many=True)
    paginated_results.object_list = serialized_results.data

    return paginated_results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one has tripped me up too. In Django, calling `only()` doesn't return data equivalent to a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT col_to_return_1, ... col_to_return_n
FROM appname_model
```

The reason it doesn't do it like this is because Django returns data to you not when you construct the QuerySet, but when you first access data *from* that QuerySet ([see lazy QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)).

In the case of `only()` (a specific example of what is called a deferred field) you still get all of the fields like you normally would, but the difference is that it isn't completely loaded in from the database immediately. When you access the data, it will only load the fields included in the only statement. Some useful docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer).

My recommendation would be to write your Serializer so that it is only taking care of the one specific filed, likely using a SerializerMethodField with another serializer to serialize your related fields.

Comment: I see -- that helps. It seems kind of insane that the Model QuerySet does not have an equivalent of a 'SELECT' statement ? It is a good recommendation, I was thinking that may be a solution but was trying to avoid it as I feel like it isn't as clean. But, what can you do??

Comment: It really bugged me at first, but under the hood I think it does become a select statement -- may be worth digging through ORM source code if your use case is particularly performance sensitive. 

Computationally, it seems okay, but the syntax is really a pain.